# How to find the exact time when a database dump was created in Sybase & Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, sybase

This a common scenario where a dump of the production database is backed up onto tapes as of specific times in a day like "Start of End", "End of Day", ...

These dump files can then be used to load on to a development DB server.

Once loaded onto the development DB server, how do we determine the exact time the dump file was created from the production database?

I only have access to the development database. I do not have access to the dump files or the production database.

And, this request is for both Oracle & Sybase.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is include the date and time in the export file name.